# C# Replacement for macro?

Tags: c#, macros

I'm trying to define 10 panels in my code, but absolutely do not want to do

```
public panel1();
public panel2();
etc....
```

and a quick google search tells me macros are not available in c#. Is there some kind of array I can define to use in place of a macro, or some other way I could handle this ?

Comment: Why/how would one use macros for this ?

Comment: *Of course* you can (and should) use an array. C macros don't make redundant variables any more acceptable, just slightly easier to handle.

Comment: I don't think he means a C macro - I assumed he meant Lisp.

Comment: Why would someone need macro for anything?

Comment: @manojlds Assuming you're not trolling, there's a good discussion here: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2545497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not too clear; but this is how you would define an array of Panels in C#:

```
Panel[] panels = new Panel[10];
```

You can use an initializer expression to fill in the panels:

```
Panel[] panels = new Panel[] { new Panel(), new Panel(), /* ... */ };
```

It is more likely that you want to loop over something and have some logic create the array - perhaps in a loop or as a LINQ expression, for instance:

```
Panel[] panels = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(n => new Panel(n)).ToArray();
```

Comment: If you do an initializer expression, and they're all the same (as in your example), or similar (as in 1, 2, 3...) I'd recommend doing `Panel[] panels = new Panel[10];` and then using a for loop to initialize the values.  Much cleaner.

Comment: @Tim S.: but having loops or LINQ statements in your code at that point hurts readability.  Given that you just want to construct 10 of something, the closer your code can get to 'give me 10 of something', the clearer your intent will be.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a `for` loop and add them dynamically with a few lines?  Something like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    Panel newPanel = new Panel();
    // each time through there is a new panel to use
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a generic list and the for loop mentioned above like this:

```
List<Panel> list = new List<Panel>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(new Panel());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want 10 of something, then you don't want your expression cluttered with loops or other irrelevant constructs.

I suggest using:

```
var panels = 10.Of<Panel>();
```

... which can be achieved with the following extension method:

```
public static T[] Of<T>(this int number) where T : new()
{
  var items = new List<T>();
  for (int i = 0; i < number; i ++)
  {
    items.Add(new T());
  }
  return items.ToArray();
}
```

That will keep the intent of your code much clearer.